# android app download apk file and open it (to install)

Tags: java, android

I wonder if you can help, I'm trying to download an apk file as an update after version check.
it's downloading the apk but it will not open the apk file its printing an error when trying to open the apk

error :

```
E/UpdateAPP: Update error! file:///storage/emulated/0/download/update.apk exposed beyond app through Intent.getData()
```

code :

```
public class UpdateApp extends AsyncTask<String,Void,Void> {
    private Context context;
    public void setContext(Context contextf){
        context = contextf;
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(String... arg0) {
        try {
            URL url = new URL(arg0[0]);
            HttpURLConnection c = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            c.setRequestMethod("GET");
            c.setDoOutput(true);
            c.connect();

            String PATH = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/download/";
            File file = new File(PATH);
            file.mkdirs();
            File outputFile = new File(file, "update.apk");
            if(outputFile.exists()){
                outputFile.delete();
            }
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);

            InputStream is = c.getInputStream();

            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int len1 = 0;
            while ((len1 = is.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                fos.write(buffer, 0, len1);
            }
            fos.close();
            is.close();

            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/download/" + "/update.apk")), "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK); // without this flag android returned a intent error!
            context.startActivity(intent);


        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("UpdateAPP", "Update error! " + e.getMessage());
        }
        return null;
    }}
```

my targetSdkVersion :

```
targetSdkVersion 27
```

thanks for the help

Comment: Possible duplicate of [android.os.FileUriExposedException: file:///storage/emulated/0/test.txt exposed beyond app through Intent.getData()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38200282/android-os-fileuriexposedexception-file-storage-emulated-0-test-txt-exposed)

Comment: have you solved this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since API 26, 'REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES' permission is necessary permission to achieve install apk file.

1. Make 'file_paths.xml' in res/xml folder to use FileProvider api

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <external-path name="" path="/" />
</paths>
```

2. Declare FileProvider and permission in AndroidManifest.xml

Note. I used Androidx version of FileProvider, if you don't use androidx, make sure  `android.support.v4.content.FileProvider`

```xml
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES" />

 <provider
            android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
            android:authorities="{PACKAGE_NAME}.fileprovider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/file_paths" />

</provider>
```

3. Get 'Uri' by FileProvider api and request install permission

```
private fun openFile(file: File) {
        val uri = if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 24) {
            val authority = packageName + ".fileprovider"
            FileProvider.getUriForFile(this, authority, file)
        } else {
            Uri.fromFile(file)
        }

        val myMime = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton()
        val mimeType = myMime.getMimeTypeFromExtension(file.extension)

        val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW).apply {
            setDataAndType(uri, mimeType)
            flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
            addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION)
        }

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 26 && !packageManager.canRequestPackageInstalls()) {
            startActivity(
                Intent(
                    Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_UNKNOWN_APP_SOURCES,
                    Uri.parse("package:$packageName")
                )
            )
        } else {
            intent.action = Intent.ACTION_VIEW
            startActivity(intent)
        }
    }
```

Edit -> remove specific methods using in my project.

Comment: its give error "There was a problem parsing the package"

Comment: Sir, you just saved the day! Can I buy you a beer?